# Carregando apenas View (sem Layout) - Yii Framework

Tags: javascript, yii

Estou customizando um site em [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/). E estou com dúvidas de como faço para acessar um arquivo que está dentro do diretório `protected/`. Estou usando uma função javascript para carregar apenas a `view` de `admin`, mas acho que ele está protegendo (como esperado). Ele da o `load` no `content`, mas não carrega o arquivo desejado :'(

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="nome-menu" data-nome="usuario" href="#">Usuário</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <!--carregar a view de admin aqui!!!
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".nome-menu").click(function (e) {
    $(".content").load('/MyProject/protected/views/usuario/admin.php');
});
```

Mockup:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Consegui obter sucesso com duas alterações:

1º) alterar o endereço do `load` para `load('/MyProject/index.php?r=usuario/admin')`.
onde ele acessa o `UsuarioController` à procura da função `actionAdmin()`.

2º) Na função `actionAdmin()` que está no `Controller`,  precisei setar falso para a renderização do layout da seguinte forma: `$this->layout = false;` para que não carregasse outro layout dentro do `Content`.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize **Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest** para saber se a requisição foi ajax, e em caso positivo use renderPartial(). Dessa forma você pode acessar a url '/MyProject/index.php?r=usuario/admin' tanto diretamente pelo browser como através de um load(). Os dois casos ficam contemplados.

```
public function actionAdmin()
{
    if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
    {
        // Renderizará a view SEM o layout.
        $this->renderPartial('admin');
    }
    else
    {
       // Renderizará a view COM o layout.
       $this->render('admin');
    }        
}
```